# Parsing an MKMapItem with iOS

Tags: ios, json, mapkit, nsdictionary, mkmapitem

I want access to the data in a `MKMapItem` object. After searching for information, I am asking the community. According to the Apple class reference, there are these properties:

- placemark
- isCurrentLocation
- name
- phone number
- url

If I log an `MKMapItem` I get what appears as a JSON dictionary of dictionaries such as:

- Address
- structured address
- center
- locality
- etc...

Many of the items contain information that I want, which are not default properties of `MKMapItem`. Is there a way to parse and model these items? I have tried

```
 NSDictionary *mapItemDictionary = (NSDictionary *)mapItem;

[mapItemDictionary valueForKey:@"key"];
```

, which results in a crash:

> `[<MKMapItem 0xb02d830> valueForUndefinedKey:]:` this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key address.

Comment: If `mapItem` is an MKMapItem, you can't just cast it as an NSDictionary.  What you might be seeing in the log is the placemark inside the MKMapItem which itself contains an addressDictionary property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anna Karenina is correct...

```
MKmapItem *mapItem = mapItemResponseFromLocalSearch;

NSDictionary *itemAddressDictionary = mapItem.placemark.addressDictionary;

CLLocation *location = mapItem.placemark.location

NSString *name = mapItem.name
```